# Creating an interactable Map with tkinter : Need advice on creating lines between Buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I've started learning Python to create a third party application for a video game. Before dealing with the connection between the application and the game client, I'm trying to create a map with tkinter.

I'm using Buttons and lines on a Canvas. Each Button represents a location, connected with another Button by a specific line. For example, Button1 and Button2 are connected by a line that goes from (center of Button1) to (center of Button2).

I've created a function that allows me to easily create a Button at a specific location :

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)

def system(system_name, position_x, position_y):
    Button(root, text = system_name).place(x=position_x, y=position_y, width=60, height=20)

# examples : 

system("Location1", 10,10)
system("Location2", 50,50)

canvas.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to create a similar function to create a line between 2 buttons. It's easy to manually calculate the center positions of each button, but doing do for several thousands buttons would be quite time consuming.

Would it be possible to create a function like this :

```
def line(system1, system2):
    system1 = center position of system1 = (a,b)
    system2 = center position of system2 = (c,d)
    canvas.create_line((a,b),(c,d))
```

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you in advance.

---

Edit : Gonna try to re-ask my question in more simple terms :

- I want to make canvas lines between buttons.
- Lines go from center to center of buttons.
- I use the following function to create buttons :

  ```
  def system(system_name, position_x, position_y):
      Button(root, text=system_name).place(x=position_x, y=position_y)
  ```
- Examples :

  ```
  a = system("Location1", 10,20)
  b = system("Location2", 40,50)
  ```
- Question : How can I re-use the parameters of the previous examples in another function that creates a line between a and b ?
- What I imagine this function would look like:

  ```
  def line(a, b):   # line between button a and button b
      c = (10 + whatever_width/2, 20 + whatever_height/2)
      d = (40 + whatever_width/2, 50 + whatever_height/2) 
      canvas.create_line(c,d)
  ```
- Any idea ?

Comment: You could use `canvas.create_window(x, y, window=button, anchor='center')` to put the buttons on the canvas instead of `place`. That way your buttons are part of the canvas like the lines and it will be easier if you want to scroll the canvas later.